# How to return a default boolean value in java streams if element not found?

Tags: java, string, java-stream, option-type, ignore-case

I want to determine if a given string matches - ignoring case - one of the elements in a `List<String>`.

I'm trying to achieve this with Java 8 streams. Here's my attempt using `.orElse(false)`:

```
public static boolean listContainsTestWord(List<String> list, String search) {
    if (list != null && search != null) {
        return list.stream().filter(value -> value.equalsIgnoreCase(search))
          .findFirst().orElse(false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but that doesn't compile.

How should I code it to return whether a match is found or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a one-liner:

```
public static boolean listContainsTestWord(List<String> list, String search) {
    return list != null && search != null && list.stream().anyMatch(search::equalsIgnoreCase);
}
```

Don't even bother with a method:

```
if (list != null && search != null && list.stream().anyMatch("someString"::equalsIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
public static boolean listContainsTestWord(List<String> list, String search) {
    if (list != null && search != null) {
        return list.stream().anyMatch(search::equalsIgnoreCase);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You have an error because `findFirst()` returns an `Optional<String>` since your Stream pipeline is composed of `String` elements. As such, you can't invoke `orElse` with a `boolean` argument (only a `String` argument would be valid).

A direct solution to your problem would be to use

```
findFirst().isPresent();
```

This way, if `findFirst()` returns an empty optional, `isPresent()` will return `false` and if it does not, it will return `true`.

But it would be better to go with @Tagir Valeev's answer and use `anyMatch`.